# Echo multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function that returns an array.
When using `print_r` it gives me something like this;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => LTEforServiceProvider
            [key] => network
            [parameters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => APN1
                            [value] => apn.qwerty.com
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => APN2
                            [value] => *
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => QCI
                            [value] => 9
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How will this look a like when it is hard coded in php, and how should I print it with a `foreach` loop?

This array is pretty overwhelming and it confuse me a lot. I know, honestly, this is a silly question, and is probably already asked sometime.

I want it in a table, something like this;

[image]

PHP, Symfony, and all other programming still confuse me a lot and I really have a hard time with it. If anybody can please help me out would be really great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an HTML table ?
Here.. this will align the data accordingly in the table format(Please use the css border property to set the table borders while testing locally)

```
<?php

$array = YOUR_ARRAY_HERE;

$table = "<table>";
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  foreach($value as $k => $v){
  if(is_array($v)){
    $table .= "<tr><td>Parameters</td><td><table>";
    foreach($v as $pk => $pv){
        $table .= "<tr><td>".$pv['id']."/".$pv['value']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $table .="</table></td></tr>";
  }
    else{
        $table .= "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td></tr>";
    }  
  }   
}
$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;
?>
```

Updated fiddle : https://eval.in/537312

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect. One thing; what if I have more than one array in the main array. Do you understand? In this example it is  `$array = array
        (
            0 => array(
                ...
                ... al the information and other arrays inside
                ...
                )`
 So how do I print multiple tables if I have it like this; `$array = array
        (
            0 => array(
                ...
                ...
                ...
                ),
            1=> array(...
                ... al the other data and arrays inside
                ...)`?

Comment: @Mentos93 simply add a nested loop to iterate, see the updated answer